# How to stop DefaultListableBeanFactory from implicitly creating LocalValidatorFactoryBean instance

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I am using Spring 3.1 and have the following spring config where I explicitly create `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` using my own `ValidationMessageSource`. I have Hibernate Validator 4.1 in my class path.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>ValidatorMsgID</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>
```

However I noticed that the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is being created twice by hitting a debug in classes `afterPropertiesSet` method. The first time is for the explicite bean that I defined in the spring config, however following that the same class is instantiated implicitly again by `DefaultListableBeanFactory` class - obviously this time with no `validationMessageSource`. Therefore it seems that when Spring does make use of the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` its using the one with the default Hibernates `messagesource` rather than the one I have specified.

**Ok, looking into this a bit further its seems that this is caused by `mvc:annotation-driven` I have in the spring config.
Any pointers would still help**

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I got it sorted eventually by adding the validator attribute to "mvc:annotation-driven". This is how my final spring config looks

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycompany.msgs.ValidatorMsgID</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="messageSource"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>
```