# Spring @ControllerAdvice messageSource doesn't work with Hibernate message parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to add some custom bean validation in a Spring Boot REST controller, extending the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class with a `@ControllerAdvice` annotation and overriding the `#handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)` method. In this method I'm trying to convert the given `FieldError` via the `messageSource` into a localized message. Although I'm receiving a `NumberFormatException` when trying to using message parameters which are be possible via the Hibernate validator.

I'm using the following dependencies:

- `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator` (6.0.11.Final)
- `org.springframework:spring-web` (5.0.8.RELEASE)
- `org.springframework:spring-webmvc` (5.0.8.RELEASE)

All included via `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` (2.0.4.RELEASE).

Consider using the following REST controller:

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/foo")
    public void submitFooRequest(@Validated @RequestBody FooRequest fooRequest) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

The FooRequest bean has a custom bean validation annotation & constraint validator:

The bean FooRequest:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ValidBarRequest
public class FooRequest {

    private String fieldFoo;
    private BarRequest barRequest;
}
```

The bean BarRequest:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BarRequest {

    private String fieldBar;
}
```

The validation annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = BarRequestValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidBarRequest {

    String message() default "{org.example.validation.constraints.ValidBarRequest.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String fieldFoo() default "fieldFoo";

    String barRequestFieldBar() default "barRequest.fieldBar";
}
```

The validation constraint validator:

```
@Log4j2
public class BarRequestValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidBarRequest, Object> {

    // ....

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (/* some condition */) {
            HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateValidatorContext = constraintValidatorContext.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
            hibernateValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            hibernateValidatorContext.addMessageParameter("fieldFoo", "some value...").buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{org.example.validation.constraints.ValidBarRequest.message}")
                .addPropertyNode("barRequest.fieldBar").addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

However via a @ControllerAdvice annotated bean and using a Spring messageSource a NumberFormatException is thrown on the following message (in messages.properties):

`ValidBarRequest.fooRequest.barRequest.fieldBar=must be lower or equal than {fieldFoo}`

The @ControllerAdvice bean:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException e, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        List<ErrorDetails> errorDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FieldError fieldError : e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errorDetails.add(new ErrorDetails(fieldError.getField(), messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, Locale.getDefault())));
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    class ErrorDetails {

        private String field;
        private String message;
    }
}
```

This causes the following exception: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fieldFoo"`

What am I doing wrong? Also I included the following bean in my `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(MessageSource messageSource) {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactory.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);

    return localValidatorFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The populate the variables in the message source MessageFormat.format is and there you must use numbers in curly braces.

```
ValidBarRequest.fooRequest.barRequest.fieldBar=must be lower or equal than {0}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your response, however {0}, {1} or {2}, etc. do not resolve the custom added message parameter like my fieldFoo value "some value...."

Comment: Sure because you are mixing Spring message resources and Hibernate Validator. Have a look at the hibernate Validator doc: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-message-interpolation

Comment: And this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884795/cant-get-hibernate-validator-working-with-spring-messagesource